# Asks a question; never responds to answers/comments

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests

What do we call someone who asks a question and never responds to answers/comments?

Think of it more as "a pattern of behavior" (somebody who has asked many questions and never responded).
I had *unresponsive* in mind, but that doesn't say that they *asked* in the first place.

Comment: You mean on a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Was it a rhetorical question?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, and preferably in general wider use, as well.

Comment: *Unengaged, disengaged?* We often speak of someone being *engaged* in conversation when they're actively involved in a two-way communication, and it's certainly possible to speak in [a disengaged tone](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22a+disengaged+tone%22&pbx=1&oq=%22a+disengaged+tone%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=278251l291455l5l292220l21l19l0l0l0l0l219l2513l6.12.1l19l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2ce18aafd4b76dc6&biw=1137&bih=741) when you don't really care what you're saying or what reply you might get.

Comment: A bad listener.

Comment: @Alenanno: Is there one on the SE, you didn't say.

Comment: @Kris, Please edit the question and indicate where you plan to use the desired word or phrase, and what slant you prefer: pejorative, neutral, other. Does it make sense to offer a bounty for answers to an underspecified question?

Comment: @jwpat7: I have edited the post adding a bit more. Pl also see the new line I had added in the bounty offer.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question without knowing the questioner's motivation. They could have become bored, distracted, arrested, or even killed and each case would be described differently.

Comment: @sml, when I answered I understood the "never" in the question to mean a pattern of behavior (somebody who has asked many questions and never responded), but now I see that that might not be what OP meant.  Kris, could you clarify?

Comment: @sml: also, Monica. That *was* what I meant. I did not mean someone who just happens to be unable to follow up. Your definition is perfect, Monica: "... a pattern of behavior (somebody who has asked many questions and never responded)", I am adding that to the OP.

Comment: Why does it appear like one of the answers has been completely deleted along with several comments related to it? Anyone can throw some light on this?

Comment: Bounty: @Monica Cellio. Way ahead of other suggestions. *Drive-by* as a  prefix tops!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps *drive-by asker* or *drive-by participant*, to convey that he comes in, makes his post/comment/etc, and then continues on his merry way.  Related, from @onomatomaniak in comments: *ask and run*.

In other contexts we call someone who takes but never gives -- for example, communal snacks at work -- a *mooch* (or *moocher*) or a *parasite*.  Depending on the specific case I don't see a problem with using those words online.  *Freeloader* also comes to mind, though it is more general.

Edited for question revision: *mooch*, *parasite*, and *freeloader* are all perjorative; the *drive-by* phrases are probably slightly negative but not as much as those.

Comment: I liked the thought experiment on the lines of *drive-by asker*.

Comment: In the vein of drive-by asker, there would also be the *ask and run*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak, nice one!

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Now we are getting pretty close. What I was thinking was just that, the hit and run driver's equivalent in a general sense.

Comment: +1 Way ahead of other suggestions. *Drive-by* as a  prefix tops! Thank you.

Comment: @Kris, glad to help!

Comment: +1 for _ask and run_, since _post and run_ is already an established term on message boards and forums. This would be a very straightforward Stack Exchange version of that.

Answer (score 6):

I like [nonreciprocal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonreciprocal).

**re·cip·ro·cal** Interchanged, given, or owed to each other

Answer (score 6):

*Distracted*.  It's possible that a person who was interested enough to ask a question, but didn't follow through with the process of discerning a helpful answer, was distracted by something else. It could be a shiny object, or it could be a sick child. It could be one or more of any number of things.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a single word that captures what you want to say. These terms come to mind:

- unappreciative of the help offered
- uninvolved in the learning process
- exhibits poor etiquette concerning questions asked
- lacks follow-through
- is half-hearted (or apathetic) about his questions

Comment: Thanks, @TheEnglishChicken. Wish there was one that captures most of the above list!

Comment: Wish there were some which are neutral, though.

Answer (score 4):

How about *deadbeat*? In the same way that a *deadbeat dad* spawns a human life that he does not concern himself to care for, a *deadbeat asker* could be construed as a person that spawns a discussion that he neglects to contribute to.

Comment: +1 This is very much like it. Can only use in a negative sense. @David Rivers: But whatabout Sarah's [see above] concerns?

Comment: I understand, but lack sympathy, for such a distracted asker. The scenario reminds me of agreeing to have lunch with someone who then spends the entire time playing with her mobile device. If an asker is going to provoke a conversation, then she should have the respect for answerers to see it through.

Comment: @David Rivers, & Kris Unless they're expecting emergency-level information, I'd say the distracted lunch partner is exhibiting a highly objectionable form of rudeness, because it's a one-on-one, personal situation, etc. I'd rate lower the rudeness of the stack exchange _asker_ distracted from the expected and desired follow through. I'd suggest a sliding scale of perceived rudeness dependent upon the distraction involved. If due to an emergency, I'd not see it as rude. Of course, we're not privy tot that info. However, I think deadbeat dads are in a (low) class all their own.

Comment: I am not looking for terms with negative connotations as such, so how negative something is, is not really an issue anyway. Still researching for a phrase that is convenient and, maybe, politically correct as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest the following adjectives:

- **unresponsive**: not reacting in a suitable way to what people say or do.
  (unresponsive to: *Helen has been unresponsive to all my suggestions.*)
- **impassive**: not showing any emotion.
- **impervious**: not affected by something or not seeming to notice it.
- **insusceptible**:  not easily influenced or affected.
- **pachydermatous**:  thick-skinned (see its definition below).
- **stolid**: showing little or no emotion or interest.
- **thick-skinned**: insensitive to criticism or hints.

If you ask me which one I prefer, I say **thick-skinned**. **Unresponsive** is also a good choice and can be used in more formal contexts. Note that the above terms may have different meanings in different contexts. I gave the related meanings with respect to your question.

Comment: You make it difficult to choose from equally good alternatives! However, any of these could also be someone who formally does respond in some way. It isn't obvious that he failed to respond. See also the new edit.

Comment: We are now closer to the answer. We need something with the sense of *coasting* [Theta30] (hence, ?coaster) and the currency of *unresponsive* [Mehper C. Palavuzlar].

Comment: @Mepher Could you expand on that answer? Perhaps giving more detailed reasons you'd pick one of those words? Or even a better description of what they mean?

Comment: @Pureferret: Here you are.

Answer (score 3):

I'm entering this as a separate answer because it's a specific solution for this site whereas the prior answer was a general one.

*Lexical Leech*

Comment: In the right context that's perfect!

Comment: I am powerless to resist any opportunity for alliteration. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a thread over on meta SO that references this idea named [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). I've pasted the question below, but the answers in the thread are very interesting.

> What is SO's long-term solution for the Help Vampire problem?
>
> Quote from article follows:
>
> > Identifying Help Vampires can be tricky, because they look like any
> >     ordinary person (or internet user, whichever is lesser). But by
> >     closely observing an individual's behavior using this handy checklist,
> >     you too can identify Help Vampires in the field:
> >
> > - Does he ask the same, tired questions others ask (at a rate of once or
> >       more per minute)?
> > - Does he clearly lack the ability or inclination to
> >       ask the almighty Google?
> > - Does he refuse to take the time to ask
> >       coherent, specific questions?
> > - Does he think helping him must be the
> >       high point of your day?
> > - Does he get offensive, as if you need to prove
> >       to him why he should use Ruby on Rails?
> > - Is he obviously just waiting
> >       for some poor, well-intentioned person to do all his thinking for him?
> > - Can you tell he really isn't interested in having his question
> >       answered, so much as getting someone else to do his work?

Comment: Thanks, you've taken quite some trouble! A simpler way would be to just post a comment like "Related: The Help Vampire problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem -- I found the answers there very interesting."

Comment: @Kris - thanks! I'm just getting the hang of how things are done around here, so I wasn't sure if that was kosher across different boards!

Comment: If you have the privilege, you could up vote the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Unconcerned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unconcerned) and [indifferent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indifferent) came to my mind.

**EDIT**:
Monica's answer reminds me of [spectator](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spectator), [bystander](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bystander), or [onlooker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onlooker).

From my personal experience: in a software company there are typically three roles involved in a code review process, namely **author**, **reviewer**, **observer**.

An author is someone who posts his or her code for review. An reviewer is someone who must review the posted code and take some action in order for the code review process to proceed. An observer is someone who has access to the posted code and may or may not want to take a look at the code. What's more, an observer is not required to do anything if he does not want to.

I would say the question raiser in OP's case is an **author** the moment he posts the question on the site, and later he becomes an **observer**.

Comment: It would indeed be nice if he's actually observing. :) How'd you know?

Comment: @Kris In the code review process, you are entitled to observe the whole process and provide comments, however, people wouldn't know or even care whether you really do so. For example, when I am assigned an observer role, I usually pay little attention to the posted code and focus on other tasks unless I am really interested in the code others write.

Comment: Sure, that is true in code review. My comment refers to the one who asks a question and ... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think "[Moocher](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20moocher&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=QW8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=moocher&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=cV7tTsqaDub20gHc3K2yCQ&ved=0CB4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9616a4a0f3c0cb68&biw=1024&bih=767)" fits this nicely, especially the Wiktionary definition:

> A person having a tendency to repeatedly ask help of others, especially if they are making little effort to help themselves. Usually used as a pejorative

Comment: +1; moocher (or **mooch**, the noun form) captures the essence of this type of questioner. And also brings to mind the classic [Moose the Mooche](http://youtu.be/tu14kEuqGJc).

Answer (score 1):

*Hypodidact*

A new coinage inspired by "autodidact", but Google did find [a lone antecedent](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xenodidact#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=hypodidact&pbx=1&oq=hypodidact&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=82976l84426l1l84731l10l7l1l0l0l0l214l892l2.4.1l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9b333de2e4b15c4&biw=1280&bih=920).

Comment: Can't see how the root *didáskein*, (Gk: to teach) is associated with the idea at hand. Hypodidact could probably imply an under-tutored? educationally-challenged?

Comment: Granted, I am not a Greek expert. Studied the roots as an etymology aficionado, but essentially clueless in the workings of the actuall language. But in English usage, as "didact" means "one who teaches", I would think "hypodidact" means "one who under-teaches" as opposed to "under-taught".

Answer (score 1):

I didn't restrain myself to think of this as just a "pattern of behavior" but also a relationship between the participants of the discussion, and a symbiotic one at that.

Of the different symbiotic relationships, commensal and parasitic were more relevant to the question.  (*[Commensal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commensal#Adjective)*, "of a form of symbiosis in which one organism derives a benefit while the other is unaffected".  *[Parasitic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parasitic#Adjective)*, "drawing upon another organism for sustenance" or "exploiting another for personal gain.")

Since commensal is neutral and parasitic is malicious, *commensal* qualifies as my answer.
A *commensal poster* if I may.

Answer (score 1):

> What do we call someone who asks a question and never responds to
>   answers/comments?

You might call him/her a person who never gives/leaves **feedback**.

I'm tempted to add ***lurker***, *one who lurks, in particular a user of an Internet chat room or newsgroup who does not participate*

But in the OP's question the user asks questions and *then* "disappears". Perhaps a neologism is in order, 
 ***a stealth poster***, a person who posts an answer and then limits his participation to reading.