# What do you call someone who is addicted to a Q&A website?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang, neologisms, internet

I was looking for a term for someone who is addicted to a Q&A website but I came up with general terms like *nethead*, *cybernaut*, *netizen*, *internet addict* etc. You can think of adjectives like *contributive*, *helpful* or even *devoted* but they are also too general and they don't cover the "addiction" and "internet" part of the question.

Although, I'm tempted to call this person *fanatic*:

---

[image]

---

Anyway, I think there might be an online slang term for this specific type of person. For example, there is *ask-and-run* for someone who posts a question on a Q&A website and never checks back. (Related question: [What do you call a Q&A user who posts a question but never checks back?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209913/what-do-you-call-a-qa-user-who-posts-a-question-but-never-checks-back))

It seems like it is a common phenomenon as there are a lot of Q&A websites nowadays:

> There are questions asked related to Stack Overflow addiction:
>
> - [Addiction towards Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21037/addiction-towards-stack-overflow)
> - [How can I keep from getting addicted to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-stack-overflow)
>
> ---
>
> Quora has a section for this phenomenon: 
>   http://www.quora.com/Quora-Addiction
>
> ---
>
> There are questions on [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110304222205AAwf4IQ) about how to stop Yahoo Answers addiction:
>
> - [How do you stop the yahoo answers addiction?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006040901681)
> - [Yahoo!Answers addiction. What will you do to stop?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071221180825AAj1Otq)

So, is there any online slang term for this kind of user?

---

Related question:
[What do you call a person who is always online on the Internet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-always-online-on-the-internet)

Comment: Maybe they're called a SEx (Stack Exchange) addict.

Comment: Are you looking for a "slang term whose *only* definition is 'addicted to a Q&A website'?"

Comment: @Mazura: Correct. But there can be details of course.

Comment: How about a "selfie-net junkie" Q&A websites are also about displaying one's knowledge, gaining recognition/approval and winning some form of reward i.e. rep points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

New and Improved; Made-Up Definitions:

> **Altruistic Vampire** -one who subsists on the dopamine released when they help another; for whatever personal motivation: an addict of altruism; someone [addicted](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/thai-nguyen/hacking-into-your-happy-c_b_6007660.html) to answering questions online. -Similar and often found in conjunction, though not to be confused with: Stack Exchange; *[Rep-Whore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151320/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-rep-whoring)*.
>
> **Cyber Vampire** -one who subsists on the dopamine released when they telecommunicate with other people; someone addicted to interpersonal relations which can only be found online.

Until I looked it up, *this is* what I thought [Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) meant (apparently it means [ne'er-do-well](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ne%27er-do-well)).

Any 'new' word is just window dressing for the word *addict*. Like this 5yo question that seems to be getting along just fine: [*How addicted to Stack Overflow are you?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you).

Internet traffic tracking sites have a category for *addicts*. IIRC, of the two SE sites that are on the top 100 list, ~50% of its users are addicts. I hope I can safely make the assumption that way more of that 50% are *altruistic* than *help*. Therefor I just call <strike>myself</strike> them (for good or evil) a

**Stack Exchange Addict**.

For a definitive answer we'd need to know *why* they're addicted; are they a rep whore or one of the two vampires? We need more information to narrow down this *obsession*. However once we have it, we no longer need this mysterious all encompassing word for "someone who is addicted to a Q&A website".

Although fitting, I believe it would be a stretch to call them *[trolls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29)*. It would be immediately misunderstood; *crossing this bridge requires you to read my answer to your question*.

We're all trolls. It just depends on which side of the Schwartz you're on; the Up side or the Down side.

Comment: Anyone addicted to Yahoo anything is an *idiot*. -Stack Exchange FTW

Comment: Great answer Mazura. I will wait for a while to see if I will get other answers.

Comment: My friend suggested that I am a *Stack Head*.

Comment: Actually, Stack Head sounds pretty appropriate.

Comment: [Arron](http://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/)- "I've been addicted to (stack|crack) overflow for 45 day, and lovin' each one or them."

Comment: [CreationEdge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21732304#21732304) - "You made me think things, and now you must suffer my sharing them."

Answer (score 10):

Having grown up in the 60's and 70's, and surviving all the addictions of the 80's and 90's, I'm ready to settle down and be a

---

### Stackhead

---

***[Stack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stack)***

> NOUN
>
> 1A pile of objects, typically one that is neatly arranged:

"The screen on my MacBook pro 4, is cluttered with stacks of windows, each stacked with 12 tabs of StackExchange pages, so that I can easily move from question to question. Of course, my desk is swamped with stacks of dictionaries, thesauruses and sundry reference books, because stackexchange has stacks of questions to answer."

[***Head***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/head)

> NOUN
>
> The head regarded as the location of intellect, imagination, and
>   memory:
>
> "I have all the irregular verbs in Webster's Ninth Collegiate
>   Dictionary conjugated in my head."
>
> informal A headache, especially one resulting from intoxication.
>
> "I woke up this morning with a splittin' head, and my wife had the
>   gall to turn the lights on."
>
> a [person](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=head) who is addicted to any or all mind altering substances.

"I started as an egg head, worked my way through pot head, meschead, acidizer and crack head, so I have just enough brain cells left to be a stackhead."

***NOT!***

: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stack

: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/head

: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=head

Cred to Mazura who suggested the phrase at 3:07 on Dec 6.

Comment: Bounty is such a rush! If had read the comment by @Mazura, I might have demurred, but I have now conformed to CC-BY-SA

Answer (score 0):

obsessed
this is 36 characters. I counted it.

Comment: Please review the help center's guidance on [writing good answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer); fuller explanations are preferred, with suitable references and examples.

Answer (score -1):

A pedant; or in your particular case a, 'cyber pedant'.)

Comment: There are a [few sources](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=4Rh9VN7jLYeN8QfXpYHABQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22cyber+pedant%22&start=20) on Google with "cyber-pedant" but couldn't be sure if it is used for this sense. Any further explanation? (not my down-vote)